# `0` values are not shown when I put a string value filter SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT DISTINCT ISNULL(a.[BPOAGE], 0) AS BPOAGE, a.[BPOAttic]
FROM [Legacy].[dbo].[MyTables] as a
```

**Result :**

[image]

```
SELECT DISTINCT ISNULL(a.[BPOAGE], 0) AS BPOAGE, a.[BPOAttic]
FROM [Legacy].[dbo].[MyTables] as a
where (a.[BPOAGE] not in ('New'))
```

**Result :**

[image]

**Q :** Can you tell me why `0` values are not shown when I put this condition `a.[BPOAGE] not in ('New')`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sql works on Three valued logic.It considers NULL as unknown,since it is unknown it will not got selected in the condition you write.If you want to include null rewrite the code as

```
SELECT DISTINCT ISNULL(a.[BPOAGE], 0) AS BPOAGE,a.[BPOAttic] FROM [Legacy].
    [dbo].[MyTables] as a where (a.[BPOAGE] not in ('New') or a.[BPOAGE] is null)
```

Comment: I don't need to include `NULL`.I need to include `0`.How can I do that?

Comment: Above query selects null value and replace it to 0 since you used ISNULL(a.[BPOAGE], 0)

Comment: Oh...Got That.Thanks a lot :)